# iPhone mail doesn't show email address anymore

Tags: iphone, email, contacts

I used to be able to click the name of the sender or the recipient and it brings up the contact information with the sender/recipient's email address highlighted in blue if I have multiple email addresses saved for the contact. It doesn't do this anymore. How do I enable it again?

Answer (score 4):

Clicking on the sender or recipient name from within an e-mail header of the iOS Mail app opens the contact information page. This is extremely unfortunate because sometimes a contact can have several e-mail addresses associated with it. In these cases, it is impossible to determine the recipient/ sender e-mail address from within the iOS mail app.

The only fix for this issue is to use a different mail app which doesn't coddle its users in such helpful ways.